# Line plot that changes color over "time"

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains *x* and *y* coordinates for a random walk that moves in discrete steps (1 step up, down, left, or right). I'd like to plot the path---the points connected by a line. This is easy, of course. The difficulty is that the path crosses over itself and becomes difficult to interpret. I add jitter to the points to avoid overplotting, but it doesn't help distinguish the ordering of the walk.

I'd like to connect the points using a line that changes color over "time" (steps) according to a thermometer-like color scale.

My random walk is stored in its own class and I'm writing a specific `plot` method for it, so if you have suggestions for how I can do this using `plot`, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefer not to use ggplot,  then `?segments`  will do what you want. -- I'm assuming here that x and y are both functions of time, as implied in your example.

Comment: Maybe just me, but ggplot didn't work for me as it seemed to sort the data first (or at least that is how the result appeared). It works fine for something like a 1d random walk over time, but not a 2d like Charlie asked where time is represented by colour.

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty easy to do in `ggplot2`:

```
so <- data.frame(x = 1:10,y = 1:10,col = 1:10)
ggplot(so,aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = 1,colour = col))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use ggplot, you can set the colour aesthetic:

```
library(ggplot2)
walk <-cumsum(rnorm(n=100, mean=0)) 
dat <- data.frame(x = seq_len(length(walk)), y = walk)
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y, colour = x)) + geom_line()
```