# R: prevent break in line showing time series data using ggplot geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot2 I want to draw a line that changes colour after a certain date. I expected this to be  be simple, but I get a break in the line at the point the colour changes. Initially I thought this was a problem with `group` (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358953/the-appliance-of-geom-line-in-ggplot) question; [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841552/line-plot-that-changes-color-over-time) also looked relevant but wasn't quite what I needed). Having messed around with the `group` aesthetic for 30 minutes I can't fix it so if anybody can point out the obvious mistake...

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(1111)
mydf <- data.frame(mydate = seq(as.Date('2013-01-01'), by = 'day', length.out = 10),
    y = runif(10, 100, 200))
mydf$cond <- ifelse(mydf$mydate > '2013-01-05', "red", "blue")

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = mydate, y = y, colour = cond)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_colour_identity(mydf$cond) +
    theme()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `group=1`, then 1 will be used as the group value for all data points, and the line will join up.

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = mydate, y = y, colour = cond, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_identity(mydf$cond) +
  theme()
```

Comment: Bah! Having searched my own code base I have realised that I have used this trick before but so long ago that I forgot it! Thanks for the reminder.